# Static graphs with nativescript

Tags: nativescript

How can I build statistic charts with nativescript,I asked if there is any module or tutorial or something else ?

Comment: you need to update your post with the code you tried .. if not more down votes which leads to query deletion

Comment: This type of question maybe better asked on the {N} slack channel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You most probably want to take a look at [Telerik UI for NativeScript](http://www.telerik.com/nativescript-ui/chart). Be advised that this is a set of *payed* components (with support etc). They're free to try.

That being said, thanks to the architecture of NativeScript, you can use whatever iOS Cocoa Pod/Android Library you want to. E.g. [Charts for iOS](https://cocoapods.org/pods/charts). See e.g. https://www.nativescript.org/blog/details/using-cocoapods-is-a-piece-of-cake-with-nativescript-1.3.0.

For a seasoned developer, implementing a Android Lib/Cocoa Pod is not that big of a deal but the easiest route would definitely be to use the readymade Telerik UI component.